# how to use a resource referencing to a parent view?

Tags: android, layout, constraints, tablet

I have a lyaout and I want to change its constraints in phone vs. tablet.

I want to set the top_toTop to be in relate to viewA while in phone device

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewA"
```

And I want it to relate to the aprent while in tablet device

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

I thought to use [resource referencing](http://shikherverma.com/blog/Referencing-In-Android) but how do i reference to the parent? it's not a resource

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Instead of using `parent` you can use the id of the parent view (the ConstraintLayout itself), this way you could swap just the id with a configuration-specific resource. Say your layout looks like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        ...
        >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/someView"
        ...
        />

    <View
        ...
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/myAnchorView"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can then define 2 different id references in your configuration, say phone:

```
<resources>
    <item name="anchorView" type="id">@id/rootView</item>
</resources>
```

And tablet:

```
<resources>
    <item name="anchorView" type="id">@id/someView</item>
</resources>
```

**Option 2**

Define a style for your view and have 2 versions of that style, one for phone:

```
<style name="MyView">
    <item name="layout_constraintTop_toTopOf">parent</item>
</style>
```

and one for tablet:

```
<style name="MyView">
    <item name="layout_constraintTop_toTopOf">@+id/viewA</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

the code you have `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` is correct but you have to put in the correct layout folder

you could also create 2 dimens files with the ids

> phone

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="view_parent">@id/viewA</dimen>
</resources>
```

> tablet

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="view_parent">@id/parentId</dimen>
</resources>
```

> layout

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@dimen/view_parent"
```

Comment: so i have to duplicate the whole layout? cannot be done by runtime resolving of the resource reference?

Comment: you can put dynamically https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet

Comment: can you put an @id in dimens.xml?

Comment: dimen is of type integer. so is @id
that's why it compiles but i don't think it will change the constraint de facto